# How to extend the Auth within a package?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, package, laravel-4

How can I extend `Auth` in order to use my own package authentication system?

I replaced the auth driver and registered my `ServiceProvider`, but what do I have to put inside its `register()` method?

The following code doesn't work:

```php
Auth::extend('example', function($app) {
    $provider =  new Vendor\Package\PackageUserProvider;
    return new \Illuminate\Auth\Guard($provider, $app['session']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do it like that:

```php
\Auth::extend('example', function()
    {
        return new Guard(
            new ExampleUserProvider(
                new BcryptHasher,
                \Config::get('auth.model')
            ),
            \App::make('session')
        );
    });
```

This will create a new guard. The first parameter is an instance of your `UserProvider` which should implement `UserProviderInterface`. The second parameter is where the guard should store the authenticated user info - in this case the session object created in the IoC.

Comment: Thanks @faust, but your code returns the following error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::extend()`

Comment: That's weird. Where did you put the code? Try without the backslash before Auth and put it in app/start/global.php. Don't forget to add use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I put your code inside `register()` method instead of `boot()`. Thanks again!